# CSS Drawing on an Angle

Tags: javascript, css

My CSS looks as follows:

```
.block1 {

 height:20px;
 width:70px;
 background-color:#09F;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 position:absolute;

}
```

This draws a rectangle. Next i would like to draw a rectangle on an angle, such as at 45 degrees. I am not aware of an angle option, how could i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not fully supported in all browsers, but you can use CSS Rotation.  [Here's an article on it](http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate).

Basically, apply:

```
-moz-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); /* WebKit (Chrome, Safari) */
-o-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Opera */
-ms-transform:rotate(45deg); /* IE9 */
transform: rotate(45deg); /* No support currently, but hooray future! */

/* Fun IE code (you should probably put this in a separate css file controlled with conditional comments) */
/* IE8+ - must be on one line, unfortunately */ 
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.7071067811865474, M12=-0.7071067811865477, M21=0.7071067811865477, M22=0.7071067811865474, SizingMethod='auto expand')";  
/* IE6 and 7 */ 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(
         M11=0.7071067811865474,
         M12=-0.7071067811865477,
         M21=0.7071067811865477,
         M22=0.7071067811865474,
         SizingMethod='auto expand');
/* These are necessary for the IE code only */
margin-left: 5px; 
margin-top: -70px;
```

IE code generated with [this tool](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/index.html), which is incredibly useful.

Comment: Also add `transform: rotate(45deg);` (without vendor-prefix). Just in case someone makes a new layout engine.

Comment: `.BasicImage` can only rotate in 90 degree increments, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb554293(v=vs.85).aspx. Also, `transform: rotate(45deg);` should come last, otherwise the "experimental" vendor prefixed property could override the "finalized" property.

Comment: @thirtydot Interesting, the article had it rotating to 1.5; I thought it might be some "undocumented" code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transform) ([from CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/)) with the value `rotate(45deg)`, and the vendor prefixed property variants:

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/JngyN/

```
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

Making it work properly in older versions of IE is.. difficult.

I recommend that you use this tool which makes it relatively easy:

http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/index.html

Answer (score 0):

here is the IE version for matrix

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.7071, M12=-0.7071, M21=0.7071, M22=0.7071, SizingMethod='auto expand');
```